# Trigger validation of all fields in Angular Form submit

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm using this method: http://plnkr.co/edit/A6gvyoXbBd2kfToPmiiA?p=preview to only validate fields on blur. This works fine, but I would also like to validate them (and thus show the errors for those fields if any) when the user clicks the 'submit' button (not a real submit but a data-ng-click call to a function)

Is there some way to trigger validation on all the fields again when clicking that button?

Comment: Where is the button in the plunkr?

Comment: sorry, the plunker is what I based my code on..I made a fork to resemble my situation more closely: http://plnkr.co/edit/VfvCSmjlzpIgUH4go2Jn?p=preview

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What worked for me was using the `$setSubmitted` function, which first shows up in the angular docs in version 1.3.20.

In the click event where I wanted to trigger the validation, I did the following:

```
vm.triggerSubmit = function() {
    vm.homeForm.$setSubmitted();
    ...
}
```

That was all it took for me. According to the docs it "Sets the form to its submitted state." It's mentioned [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Comment: this doesn't work when you're using `ng-messages` and only showing them when *$error* && *$dirty*.

Comment: @JobaDiniz Have you tried the $setDirty function? It's also mentioned in the link from my answer: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Hope that helps!

Comment: it doesn't work for `form`... I had to loop through all inputs and call `$setDirty()` on them.

Answer (score 43):

I know, it's a tad bit too late to answer, but all you need to do is, force all forms dirty. Take a look at the following snippet:

```
angular.forEach($scope.myForm.$error.required, function(field) {
    field.$setDirty();
});
```

and then you can check if your form is valid using:

```
if($scope.myForm.$valid) {
    //Do something
}
```

and finally, I guess, you would want to change your route if everything looks good:

```
$location.path('/somePath');
```

**Edit**: form won't register itself on the scope until submit event is trigger. Just use ng-submit directive to call a function, and wrap the above in that function, and it should work.

Comment: can you provide example of programatically triggering `ng-submit` directive?

Comment: @chovy `ng-submit` simply binds a function to the submit event, why not just call that function?

Comment: i have a directive embedded in the form which updates a form field outside the directive....the validator is not being applied unless I click and blur the form field I want validated.

Comment: i wont' have the form object that gets passed to it

Comment: @chovy I don't understand you correctly. But let me try to help you out. Have you tried validating on debounce?

Comment: I'm trying to trigger form validation from outside the form's `ng-submit` handler. You only get a form object from within there.

Comment: @chovy Could you give me some information regarding the setup of your Angular app? The controller your form resides in, is it a child controller or an independent controller?

Comment: i want to access `$scope.form` from the controller of a directive that is embedded inside the `<form>` -- `$scope.$parent.form` is undefined.

Answer (score 18):

In case someone comes back to this later... None of the above worked for me. So I dug down into the guts of angular form validation and found the function they call to execute validators on a given field. This property is conveniently called `$validate`.

If you have a named form `myForm`, you can programmatically call `myForm.my_field.$validate()` to execute field validation. For example:

```
<div ng-form name="myForm">
    <input required name="my_field" type="text" ng-blur="myForm.my_field.$validate()">
</div>
```

Note that calling `$validate` has implications for your model. From the angular docs for ngModelCtrl.$validate:

> Runs each of the registered validators (first synchronous validators and then asynchronous validators). If the validity changes to invalid, the model will be set to undefined, unless ngModelOptions.allowInvalid is true. If the validity changes to valid, it will set the model to the last available valid $modelValue, i.e. either the last parsed value or the last value set from the scope.

So if you're planning on doing something with the invalid model value (like popping a message telling them so), then you need to make sure  `allowInvalid` is set to `true` for your model.

Comment: more discussion on the very surprising "model becomes undefined" outcome in the absence of `allowInvalid` can be read here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10035

Answer (score 12):

You can use **Angular-Validator** to do what you want. It's stupid simple to use.

**It will:**

- Only validate the fields on `$dirty` or on `submit`
- Prevent the form from being submitted if it is invalid
- Show custom error message after the field is `$dirty` or the form is submitted

**[See the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwIW5GtHokTiwpe689S3?p=preview)**

**Example**

```html
<form angular-validator 
       angular-validator-submit="myFunction(myBeautifulForm)"
       name="myBeautifulForm">
       <!-- form fields here -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If the field does not pass the `validator` then the user will not be able to submit the form.

Check out [angular-validator use cases and examples](https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator) for more information.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of Angular-Validator*

Answer (score 11):

Well, the angular way would be to let it handle validation, - since it does at every model change -  and only show the result to the user, when you want.

In this case you decide when to show the errors, you just have to set a flag:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0NNCpQKhbLTYMZaxMQ9l?p=preview

As far as I know there is a issue filed to angular to let us have more advanced form control. Since it is not solved i would use this instead of reinventing all the existing validation methods.

edit: But if you insist on your way, here is your modified fiddle with validation before submit. http://plnkr.co/edit/Xfr7X6JXPhY9lFL3hnOw?p=preview
The controller broadcast an event when the button is clicked, and the directive does the validation magic.

Comment: This works in this example, but what if I, as I have in my case (but not in that plunkr..sorry!), more then one directive like that email one. Would I somehow have to move the validation out of the directives into a seperate validation class and then call all validation methods of this form, or can I somehow trigger the validation in another way for all directives. As validation is triggered by blur, maybe even trigger blurs from code, but that seems horrible.

Comment: Oh and I know about the issue. Unfortunately it is not in beta even yet and the workflow I'm talking about is a required one for this company

Comment: The broadcasted event will trigger the $on callback in every directive since all of them are under the controller's scope.

Comment: ahh..didn't really understand that part. Thanks!

Comment: I am using broadcast now, but because I would like to differentiate between the broadcasted validation trigger and the blurred one I wanted to pass a parameter, like this:   scope.$on('startValidations', validateMe('event', 'broadcast'));. This however is triggered onload, probably because of the () behind the function. Can I somehow solve this differently?

Comment: When you broadcast the event you can pass parameters.
$scope.$broadcast('startValidations', param1, param2);
The listen remains unchanged:
scope.$on('startValidations', validateMe);
And in the callback fn:
function validateMe( event, param1, param2 ) {}
See the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

Comment: thanks! Had already thought of a workaround with setting something in the controller in the global scope after the submit but this is nicer

Answer (score 9):

One approach is to force all attributes to be dirty. You can do that in each controller, but it gets very messy. It would be better to have a general solution.

The easiest way I could think of was to use a directive

- it will handle the form submit attribute
- it iterates through all form fields and marks pristine fields dirty
- it checks if the form is valid before calling the submit function

Here is the directive

```
myModule.directive('submit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, formElement, attrs) {
      var form;
      form = scope[attrs.name];
      return formElement.bind('submit', function() {
        angular.forEach(form, function(field, name) {
          if (typeof name === 'string' && !name.match('^[\$]')) {
            if (field.$pristine) {
              return field.$setViewValue(field.$value);
            }
          }
        });
        if (form.$valid) {
          return scope.$apply(attrs.submit);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And update your form html, for example:

```
 <form ng-submit='justDoIt()'>
```

becomes:

```
 <form name='myForm' novalidate submit='justDoIt()'>
```

See a full example here: http://plunker.co/edit/QVbisEK2WEbORTAWL7Gu?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Here is my global function for showing the form error messages.

```
 function show_validation_erros(form_error_object) {
        angular.forEach(form_error_object, function (objArrayFields, errorName) {
            angular.forEach(objArrayFields, function (objArrayField, key) {
                objArrayField.$setDirty();
            });
        });
    };
```

And in my any controllers,

```
if ($scope.form_add_sale.$invalid) { 
    $scope.global.show_validation_erros($scope.form_add_sale.$error);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I changed my answer. Please check it now

Answer (score 2):

Based on Thilak's answer I was able to come up with this solution...

Since my form fields only show validation messages if a field is invalid, and has been touched by the user I was able to use this code triggered by a button to show my invalid fields:

```js
// Show/trigger any validation errors for this step
angular.forEach(vm.rfiForm.stepTwo.$error, function(error) {
  angular.forEach(error, function(field) {
    field.$setTouched();
  });
});
// Prevent user from going to next step if current step is invalid
if (!vm.rfiForm.stepTwo.$valid) {
  isValid = false;
}
```

```html
<!-- form field -->
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': rfi.rfiForm.stepTwo.Parent_Suffix__c.$touched && rfi.rfiForm.stepTwo.Parent_Suffix__c.$invalid }">

  <!-- field label -->
  <label class="control-label">Suffix</label>
  <!-- end field label -->
  <!-- field input -->
  <select name="Parent_Suffix__c" class="form-control"
          ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in rfi.contact.Parent_Suffixes"
          ng-model="rfi.contact.Parent_Suffix__c" />
  <!-- end field input -->
  <!-- field help -->
  <span class="help-block" ng-messages="rfi.rfiForm.stepTwo.Parent_Suffix__c.$error" ng-show="rfi.rfiForm.stepTwo.Parent_Suffix__c.$touched">
    <span ng-message="required">this field is required</span>
  </span>  
  <!-- end field help -->
</div>
<!-- end form field -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: I know this is a hack, but it was useful for Angular 1.2 and earlier that didn't provide a simple mechanism.

The validation kicks in on the **change** event, so some things like changing the values programmatically won't trigger it. But triggering the change event will trigger the validation. For example, with jQuery:

```
$('#formField1, #formField2').trigger('change');
```

Comment: This approach is simple. Plus it has the advantage that it works on older (all) versions of Angular.

Comment: Not the `angular way`.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [this approach](http://code.realcrowd.com/on-the-bleeding-edge-advanced-angularjs-form-validation/) in handling validation on button click.

1. There is no need to invoke anything from controller,
2. it's all handled with a directive.

on [github](https://github.com/realcrowd/angularjs-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
// The controller

$scope.submitForm = function(form){
     //Force the field validation
     angular.forEach(form, function(obj){
      if(angular.isObject(obj) && angular.isDefined(obj.$setDirty))
      { 
       obj.$setDirty();
      }
     })
        
        if (form.$valid){
  
   $scope.myResource.$save(function(data){
        //....
   });
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- FORM -->

  <form name="myForm"  role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
<!-- FORM GROUP to field 1 -->
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.field1.$invalid && myForm.field1.$dirty }">
      <label for="field1">My field 1</label>
        <span class="nullable"> 
        <select name="field1" ng-model="myresource.field1" ng-options="list.id as list.name for list in listofall"
          class="form-control input-sm" required>
            <option value="">Select One</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <div ng-if="myForm.field1.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.field1.$error" ng-messages-include="mymessages"></div>
  </div>
    
<!-- FORM GROUP to field 2 -->
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.field2.$invalid && myForm.field2.$dirty }">
    <label class="control-label labelsmall" for="field2">field2</label> 
      <input name="field2" min="1" placeholder="" ng-model="myresource.field2" type="number" 
      class="form-control input-sm" required>
    <div ng-if="myForm.field2.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.field2.$error" ng-messages-include="mymessages"></div>
  </div>

  </form>

<!-- ... -->
<button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I done something following to make it work.

```
<form name="form" name="plantRegistrationForm">
  <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': (form.$submitted || form.headerName.$touched) && form.headerName.$invalid }">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="label-color">HEADER NAME 
        <span class="red"><strong>*</strong></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" name="headerName" id="headerName" 
             ng-model="header.headerName" 
             maxlength="100" 
             class="form-control" required>
      <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.headerName.$touched">
        <span ng-show="form.headerName.$invalid" 
              class="label-color validation-message">Header Name is required</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="addHeader(form, header)" 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-default pull-right">Add Header
  </button>

</form>
```

In your controller you can do;

```
addHeader(form, header){
        let self = this;
        form.$submitted = true;
        ... 
    }
```

You need some css as well;

```
.label-color {
            color: $gray-color;
        }
.has-error {
       .label-color {
            color: rgb(221, 25, 29);
        }
        .select2-choice.ui-select-match.select2-default {
            border-color: #e84e40;
        }
    }
.validation-message {
       font-size: 0.875em;
    }
    .max-width {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate all fields of my form when I want, I do a validation on each field of $$controls like this :

```
angular.forEach($scope.myform.$$controls, function (field) {
    field.$validate();
});
```