# Fix disconnect between model and view in AngularJS after unbinding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I managed to change the default on the fly validation of AngularJS to a validation onblur and on submit with help from the stackoverflow community: [Trigger validation of all fields in Angular Form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939981/trigger-validation-of-all-fields-in-angular-form-submit/16940364?noredirect=1#comment24464907_16940364)

This works fine for the validation part, but I now seem to have a problem where my models aren't set when I try to use them in the controller.

This plunk has an example where I try to log the value of user.mail: http://plnkr.co/edit/TOb2RRh6b5FenphLtSYS?p=preview

What I know I can do is this in a directive:

```
 scope.authenticate.userName = elm.val();
```

The problem with that is that would make that directive only useable for that element because it would mean hardcoding the element's modelname

Is it possible to set the value for the model in a different way, or to get the modelname into the directive and thereby make that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because you're never telling `ngModel` what the value to hold onto is (take a look at the [NgModelController docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)).

What you want to look at is the `$setViewValue` method.

I've [forked your plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/msn7WvkS7LfSRS92Z6tn?p=preview) and added a div that just dumps the user, so you can see what's going on.

The only changes I made to the controller were in the `doValidation` function:

```
function dovalidation() {
  var email = elm.val();
  if (EMAIL_REGX.test(email)) {
    ctrl.$setViewValue(email);  // set the model to the right value
    ctrl.$setValidity('emails', true);
  } else {
    ctrl.$setViewValue(null);   // invalid, so set the model to null
    ctrl.$setValidity('emails', false);
  }
}
```

Comment: great! I knew there had to be a simple method, but just couldn't find out how. Good thing you understood my somewhat messy description :-)