# Triggering angular form validation from a click handler

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-forms

I have a form that was moved into a table, losing the built in form validation features as I cannot use ng-submit:

```
<tr ng-form="controller.add.form">
  <td>New item</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" id="newName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required ng-model="controller.add.name"></td>
  <td><textarea name="description" id="newDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" ng-model="controller.add.description"></textarea></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="controller.add.save()">Save</button></td>
</tr>
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
.controller('ObjectController', ['ObjectService', function(ObjectService)
{
  var objects = this;
  objects.entries = [];
  objects.add = {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    save: function()
    {
      if(!objects.add.form.$valid) return;
      ObjectService.create(
        {name: objects.add.name, description: objects.add.description},
        function(r)
        {
          if(r && 'name' in r)
          {
            objects.add.name = '';
            objects.add.description = '';
            objects.entries.push(r);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };
  ObjectService.read({}, function(r) { objects.entries = r; });
}])
```

How can I make the save method trigger validation with standard popups when clicked?

Comment: Do you intend using $http.POST with saving the submittion?

Comment: The save method calls an angular service

Comment: @MortenNilsen Could you post the controller code?

Comment: Please check answers in [Trigger validation of all fields in Angular Form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939981/trigger-validation-of-all-fields-in-angular-form-submit)

Comment: @Artem if I call $setSubmitted() no popups appear, but I am able to properly read $valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AngularJS API Reference:

> the purpose of ngForm is to group controls, but not to be a
>   replacement for the `<form>` tag with all of its capabilities (e.g.
>   posting to the server, ...).

ngForm allows creating "form groups" within the **main parent form** that allow to validate the fields within the group individually. So you should surround the ng-form with a `<form>` or even lose the ng-form if you don't need validation by groups.

Comment: I can't surround this with a form due to it being a table row - the form does not work at all due to it being invalid html.

Comment: Maybe you can surround the whole table with `<form>` or use CSS that mimics the TABLE tag's layout: `display:table`, `display:table-row`, and `display:table-cell`. In order to use the native validation and ng-submit you have the use the `<form>` tag for now. That's a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2513

Comment: laying out tabular data without table seems like a non-starter to me. Also making the whole table a single form is equally incorrect. I guess I will just have to forego form validation feedback all together.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in the form to your click handler.

Assuming your form has a name of "myForm", change ng-click to:

```
ng-click="controller.add.save($event, myForm)"
```

And in your controller:

```
    save : function(event, form) {
            if (form.$invalid) {
                console.log('invalid');
            } else {
                console.log('valid');
            }
        }
```

Just noticed your comment about not using a form element - as Yaniv said, just surround the table with a form element:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <table>
        <tr ng-form>
            <td>New item</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="newName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required ng-model="controller.add.name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="description" id="newDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" ng-model="controller.add.description"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="controller.add.save($event, myForm)">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/qKFs3q?p=preview

Comment: I have some concerns about placing a form around the table, as the table contains hidden input elements used for editing rows on demand. This is my first angular app though, so my concerns may be misplaced without me knowing so.

Comment: Without seeing your entire app, I don't think there should be any issues doing this. As an alternative, you could try passing each of the inputs to your save function (i.e. controller.add.save($event, name, description) and inspect the angular properties for each element like name.$invalid. I haven't tried that before from a controller but suspect it should work.