# Validate form with all fields in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, validation

What is the best way to validate all the fields in AngularJS.

I have a form with 7 fields, and all are mandatory, and I want to show an error message or change in a border if any of the fields is not valid.

I use below approach. Please tell me is it correct way. What if tomorrow I have 100 fields.

```
if(!($scope.signInForm.email.$valid)){
    $scope.emailError = true;
}
else {
    $scope.emailError = false;
}
if(!($scope.signInForm.password.$valid)){
    $scope.passwordError = true;
}
else {
    $scope.passwordError = false;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use ngMessages in your view instead?

Comment: Please refer to following discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939981/trigger-validation-of-all-fields-in-angular-form-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this in the template, see more information in the doc: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

From the docs

```
<form name="myForm" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" required>

    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!
    </span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!
    </span>
  </div>
  ...

  <!-- If you want to disable the button until all fields are filled in correctly.-->
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Login</button>
</form>
```

As Alex said it's also a good idea to look into ngMessages, you can find  helpful information here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/2015/06/06/ng-messages-revisited.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  newuser = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl(''),
    lastname: new FormControl(''),
    usertype: new FormControl(''),
    phoneno: new FormControl(''),
    city: new FormControl(''),
    zip: new FormControl(''),
    agree:new FormControl('')
  });




  submitform(){
    if(this.newuser.status=="VALID"){
        console.log(this.newuser.value);   
    }   
  }
```